# Do deleted answers sort by score among visible answers here on MSE?

Tags: support, bug, deleted-answers, sorting

> [image]

Above: sorting by **votes** ([link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369594/392799) for the 10k users)

No user scripts

---

Do deleted answers sort by score among visible answers here on MSE?

Or is it something being rolled out? A bug?

It's *never* been like that on Aviation for example ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6R0S.png); also **own** answer with score 31).

---

Update: based on a reply by @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog, it is not reproducible for 10k+ users here.

Comment: Probably a bug, or a user script on your end. Deleted answers are always sorted at the end when sorting by votes.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog: no scripts; you're +10k, can you check? thx

Comment: Unable to reproduce. It appears at the very bottom, after the non-deleted -1 answer for me.

Comment: It's probably sorted with the non-deleted answers if you're viewing your *own* answer and you have <10k rep.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog: linked aviation example (score 31) is own answer, also thanks for checking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From some science I did on other sites, @Sonic's guess seems to be right. It's a behaviour only seen when you do not have the privilege to [view all deleted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) which comes at 10k reputation on regular sites (2k on beta sites). In that case, the only deleted answers you can see are your own ones, and they are all sorted by votes; no exception is made for deleted answers. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfyMV.jpg) is an example.

Comment: You're welcome. This could be a case of "we haven't really thought about this; it's just the way it is and it doesn't do much harm" a.k.a. [status-bylackofdesign].

Comment: Given the science I'm accepting this for solving the mystery, regardless if bug or overlooked. Thanks again :)